# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext leads to memory (leak) overflow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

In my code I stretch the size of an image to a specified size. The code works fine so far.
I got the problem that "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext ()" does not release the memory of the new image. So, the memory is full after about 10 minutes and the app is terminated by IOS.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
- (CCSprite *)createStretchedSignFromString:(NSString *)string withMaxSize:(CGSize)maxSize withImage:(UIImage *)signImage
{
    // Create a new image that will be stretched with 10 px cap on each side
    UIImage *stretchableSignImage = [signImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];

    // Set size for new image
    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(260.f, 78.0f);

    // Create new graphics context with size of the answer string and some cap
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);

    // Stretch image to the size of the answer string
    [stretchableSignImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, newImageSize.width, newImageSize.height)];

    // Create new image from the context
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // End graphics context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create new texture from the stretched
    CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:resizedImage];

    CCSprite *spriteWithTex = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];

    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:tex];

    [tex release];

    // Return new sprite for the sign with the texture  
    return spriteWithTex;
}
```

Called by this code:

```
// Create image from image path
UIImage *targetSignImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:targetSignFileName];

// Create new sprite for the sign with the texture
CCSprite *plainSign = [self createStretchedSignFromString:answerString withMaxSize:CGSizeMake(260.0f, 78.0f) withImage:targetSignImage];
```

Thank you so far.

Comment: Make it in NSThread and use NSAutoreleasePool.
It my suggestion.

Comment: i think createStretchedSignFromString make retain and it must be released *plainSign*

Comment: `targetSignImage`and `plainSign` are autoreleased, so i don't have to release them. I tried it already.

Comment: so, may be you don't exit from method(have cycle) and then object not autoreleased? You can try take your method in NSAutoreleasePool for experiment.

Comment: did you check with instruments on what is causing the memory to fill. does it show up in the allocation instrument? if not it's most likely that the graphics context is not correctly closed. this adds up memory to your application footprint that does not show up in the allocation tool.

Comment: I checked it with Instrument tested several times, but got no leaks. Only the memory consumption was steadily higher. "Allocations" could not show me what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.

First of all, the code shown above is correct and without leaks.

The problem was caused by the removal of the sprite that has `planSign` as child. The sprite is removed by a timer that runs on a different thread, so on an others NSAutoreleasePool.

`[timerClass removeTarget:targetWithSign]` released an empty pool.

`[timerClass performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeTarget:) withObject:targetWithSign waitUntilDone:NO];` released the correct pool, which contains the target sprite and its child `plainSign`.

Thanks to SAKrisT and stigi for your suggestions.